# Trying to make a like button but Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to make a like button and unlike but I it gives me error when I try to press the button in the simulator .if you know any other code for the like button to be much easier will be helpful  ( or some websites , yt vids)

```
@IBOutlet weak var postTextLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var subtitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var likeLabel : UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var likeBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var unlikeBtn: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.bounds.height / 2
    profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

weak var post:Post?


func set(post:Post) {
    self.post = post
    var postID : String!
    self.profileImageView.image = nil 
    ImageService.getImage(withURL: post.author.photoURL) { image , url in
        guard let _post = self.post else {return}
        if _post.author.photoURL.absoluteString == url.absoluteString {
              self.profileImageView.image = image
        }else {
            print("not the right image")
        }

    }



    usernameLabel.text = post.author.username
    postTextLabel.text = post.text
    subtitleLabel.text = post.createdAt.calenderTimeSinceNow()
}
var postID : String!

@IBAction func likePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.postID = "post_0"
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let keyToPost = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key


    ref.child("posts").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        if let post = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            let updateLikes : [ String : Any] = [ "peopleWhoLike/\(keyToPost)" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid ]
            ref.child("posts").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(updateLikes, withCompletionBlock : {(error ,reff) in
                if error == nil {
                    ref.child("posts").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of : .value, with: { (snap) in
                        if let properties = snap.value as? [ String : AnyObject] {
                            if let likes = properties["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                let count = likes.count
                                self.likeLabel.text = "\(count) Likes"

                            }
                        }
                    })
                }

            })
        }

    }
}
@IBAction func unlikedPressed(_ sender:Any) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("posts").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let properties = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            if let peopleWhoLike = properties["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                for (id,person) in peopleWhoLike {
                    if person as? String == Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid {
                        ref.child("posts").child(self.postID).child("peopleWhoLike").child(id).removeValue(completionBlock: {(error , reff)in
                            if error == nil {
                                ref.child("posts").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in
                                    if let prop = snap.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                        if let likes = prop["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                            let count = likes.count
                                            self.likeLabel.text = "\(count) Likes"
                                            ref.child("posts").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(["likes" : count])
                                        } else {
                                            self.likeLabel.text = " 0 Likes"
                                            ref.child("posts").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(["likes" : 0])

                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                            }


                        })
                        self.likeBtn.isHidden = false
                        self.unlikeBtn.isHidden = true
                        self.unlikeBtn.isEnabled = true


                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    })
    ref.removeAllObservers()

}
```

}

```
class HomeController: UIViewController,  UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch section {
    case 0:
        return posts.count
    case 1:
        return fetchingMore ? 1 : 0
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])


        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "loadingCell", for: indexPath) as! LoadingCell
        cell.spinner.startAnimating()
        return cell
    }

}


var tableView:UITableView!
var cellHeights: [IndexPath : CGFloat] = [:]

var posts = [Post]()
var fetchingMore = false
var endReached = false
let leadingScreensForBatching:CGFloat = 3.0

var refreshControl:UIRefreshControl!

var seeNewPostsButton:SeeNewPostsButton!
var seeNewPostsButtonTopAnchor:NSLayoutConstraint!

var lastUploadedPostID:String?

var postsRef:DatabaseReference {
    return Database.database().reference().child("posts")
}
var oldPostsQuery:DatabaseQuery {
    var queryRef:DatabaseQuery
    let lastPost = posts.last
    if lastPost != nil {
        let lastTimestamp = lastPost!.createdAt.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
        queryRef = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryEnding(atValue: lastTimestamp)
    } else {
        queryRef = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
    }
    return queryRef
}

var newPostsQuery:DatabaseQuery {
    var queryRef:DatabaseQuery
    let firstPost = posts.first
    if firstPost != nil {
        let firstTimestamp = firstPost!.createdAt.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
        queryRef = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryStarting(atValue: firstTimestamp)
    } else {
        queryRef = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
    }
    return queryRef
}

@IBAction func handleLogoutButton(_ sender: Any) {

    try! Auth.auth().signOut()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)

    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")
    tableView.register(LoadingCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "loadingCell")
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.90,alpha:1.0)
    view.addSubview(tableView)

    var layoutGuide:UILayoutGuide!

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        layoutGuide = view.layoutMarginsGuide
    }

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.reloadData()

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh), for: .valueChanged)


    seeNewPostsButton = SeeNewPostsButton()
    view.addSubview(seeNewPostsButton)
    seeNewPostsButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    seeNewPostsButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    seeNewPostsButtonTopAnchor = seeNewPostsButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -44)
    seeNewPostsButtonTopAnchor.isActive = true
    seeNewPostsButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32.0).isActive = true
    seeNewPostsButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: seeNewPostsButton.button.bounds.width).isActive = true

    seeNewPostsButton.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh), for: .touchUpInside)

    //observePosts()
    beginBatchFetch()


}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    listenForNewPosts()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    stopListeningForNewPosts()
}

func toggleSeeNewPostsButton(hidden:Bool) {
    if hidden {
        // hide it

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.seeNewPostsButtonTopAnchor.constant = -44.0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // show it
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.seeNewPostsButtonTopAnchor.constant = 12
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

@objc func handleRefresh() {
    print("Refresh!")

    toggleSeeNewPostsButton(hidden: true)

    newPostsQuery.queryLimited(toFirst: 20).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        var tempPosts = [Post]()

        let firstPost = self.posts.first
        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                let data = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                let post = Post.parse(childSnapshot.key, data),
                childSnapshot.key != firstPost?.id {

                tempPosts.insert(post, at: 0)
            }
        }

        self.posts.insert(contentsOf: tempPosts, at: 0)

        let newIndexPaths = (0..<tempPosts.count).map { i in
            return IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
        }

        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: newIndexPaths, with: .top)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)

        self.listenForNewPosts()

    })
}
func fetchPosts(completion:@escaping (_ posts:[Post])->()) {

    oldPostsQuery.queryLimited(toLast: 20).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        var tempPosts = [Post]()

        let lastPost = self.posts.last
        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                let data = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                let post = Post.parse(childSnapshot.key, data),

                childSnapshot.key != lastPost?.id {

                tempPosts.insert(post, at: 0)
            }
        }

        return completion(tempPosts)
    })


}
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
    if offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height * leadingScreensForBatching {
        if !fetchingMore && !endReached {
            beginBatchFetch()
        }
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellHeights[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHeights[indexPath] ?? 72.0
}


func beginBatchFetch() {
    fetchingMore = true
    self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 1), with: .fade)

    fetchPosts { newPosts in
        self.posts.append(contentsOf: newPosts)
        self.fetchingMore = false
        self.endReached = newPosts.count == 0
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            self.listenForNewPosts()
        }
    }
}

var postListenerHandle:UInt?

func listenForNewPosts() {

    guard !fetchingMore else { return }

    // Avoiding duplicate listeners
    stopListeningForNewPosts()

    postListenerHandle = newPostsQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        if snapshot.key != self.posts.first?.id,
            let data = snapshot.value as? [String:Any],
            let post = Post.parse(snapshot.key, data) {

            self.stopListeningForNewPosts()

            if snapshot.key == self.lastUploadedPostID {
                self.handleRefresh()
                self.lastUploadedPostID = nil
            } else {
                self.toggleSeeNewPostsButton(hidden: false)
            }
        }
    })
}

func stopListeningForNewPosts() {
    if let handle = postListenerHandle {
        newPostsQuery.removeObserver(withHandle: handle)
        postListenerHandle = nil
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let newPostNavBar = segue.destination as? UINavigationController,
        let newPostVC = newPostNavBar.viewControllers[0] as? NewPostViewController {

        newPostVC.delegate = self

    }
}
```

}

extension HomeController: NewPostVCDelegate {

```
func didUploadPost(withID id: String) {
    self.lastUploadedPostID = id
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

I try to make a like button and unlike but I it gives me error when I try to press the button in the simulator .if you know any other code for the like button to be much easier will be helpful  ( or some websites , yt vids)

Comment: at which line you are getting this error?

Comment: ref.child("posts").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

Comment: Are you sure `self.postID` is not empty?

Comment: I think I have to declare self.postID in newsfeed controller but I don't know how

Comment: `print(self.postID)` before `ref.child("posts").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in` and check it's value before crash.

Comment: I put a breakpoint from @ibaction like pressed to print(self.postID) and have one breakpoint at let ref = Database.database().reference()

Comment: so are you getting any values in `self.postID`?

Comment: no , finished with error - code: -1002

Comment: Can you share any demo project where I can replicate the issue?

Comment: do you have a GitHub account

Comment: It/s ok now????

Answer (score 1):

On this line

```
ref.child("posts").child(self.postID)
```

the postID is undefined which is causing the crash. In the comments you state you assign a value to it, but the code in the question doesn't include how that's being done so there's a high likelyhood that value is not being assigned.

The fix would be to assign a value to that class var before that line, like this

```
@IBAction func likePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.postID = "post_0" //or however you determine which post it is
                           // e.g. self.postID = getCurrentPostId()
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let keyToPost = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key
    ref.child("posts").child(self.postID)...
```

You may also want to implement some basic error checking as well to ensure the postID is not nil before trying to call the Firebase function.

```
if let postID = getCurrentPostID() {
   //perform the firebase function using postID
} else {
   //display an error 'not post selected'
}
```

Comment: @isaa If you can elaborate a bit, and perhaps update your question with the error, what line it occurred on, we may be able to help further.

Comment: GitHub account?

Comment: @isaa That's not really how this site works as it would not help future readers. Remember this is a repository of code specific questions and solutions to that question so if the question includes code that is off site, future readers will not be able to refer to it. Please take a moment and review the guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update your question with relevant code and we'll take a look!